# how to draw the angle bisector of a triangle

Tags: coordinates, technical-drawing, angle, tikz-angles

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath,amssymb,tkz-euclide}
    \usetkzobj{all}
    \usepackage{color}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}% To get more advances positioning options
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}% To get more arrow heads
\usepackage{amsthm,color}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,plotmarks}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,angles}


\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{exinn}{Example}[chapter]
\newenvironment{example}
  {\clubpenalty=10000
   \begin{exinn}%
   \mbox{}%
   {\color{blue}\leaders\hrule height .8ex depth \dimexpr-.8ex+0.8pt\relax\hfill}%
   \mbox{}\linebreak\ignorespaces}
  {\par\kern2ex\hrule\end{exinn}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter One}
\section{Section One}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[blue, very thick]
    (0,0) coordinate (a) node[black,left] {A}
    -- (2,4) coordinate (b) node[black,above] {B}
    -- (7,0) coordinate (c) node[black,right] {C}
    pic["$\alpha$", draw=orange, -, angle eccentricity=1.2, angle radius=1cm]
    {angle=a--b--c}
        pic["$\beta$", draw=orange, -, angle eccentricity=1.2, angle radius=1cm]
    {angle=c--a--b}
        pic["$\gamma$", draw=orange, -, angle eccentricity=1.2, angle radius=1cm]
    {angle=b--c--a}-- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run with `xelatex` or use package `auto-pst-pdf` and `pdflatex`

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-1,-1)(7.5,5)
\pstGeonode[PointSymbol=none,PosAngle={180,90,0}](0,0){A}(2,4){B}(7,0){C}
\pspolygon[linecolor=blue,linewidth=1pt](A)(B)(C)
\pstMarkAngle[linecolor=red,MarkAngleRadius=0.8]{C}{A}{B}{$\alpha$}
\pstMarkAngle[linecolor=red,MarkAngleRadius=0.8]{A}{B}{C}{$\beta$}
\pstMarkAngle[linecolor=red,MarkAngleRadius=0.8]{B}{C}{A}{$\gamma$}
\pstBissectBAC[linestyle=none,PointSymbol=none,PointName=none]{C}{A}{B}{A'}
\pstBissectBAC[linestyle=none,PointSymbol=none,PointName=none]{A}{B}{C}{B'}
\pstBissectBAC[linestyle=none,PointSymbol=none,PointName=none]{B}{C}{A}{C'}
\pstInterLL[PointName=none]{A}{B}{C}{C'}{AB}\psline[linestyle=dashed](C)(AB)
\pstInterLL[PointName=none]{B}{C}{A}{A'}{BC}\psline[linestyle=dashed](A)(BC)
\pstInterLL[PointName=none]{C}{A}{B}{B'}{CA}\psline[linestyle=dashed](B)(CA)
\rput(A){\psline[linecolor=red](0.8;{(A')})}
\rput(B){\psline[linecolor=red](0.8;{(B')})}
\rput(C){\psline[linecolor=red](0.8;{(C')})}
\end{pspicture}    

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

As you are loading `tkz-euclide` anyway, you could simply make use of it. I used the fact that `tkz-euclide` has the incenter defined, and on p. 32 would be an even shorter code but with there the lines overshoot. And I am using [Ulrike Fischer's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/419508/121799), which is using a syntax that is sometimes said to be deprecated but works fine for this intersection of lines.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,angles}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[blue, very thick]
    (0,0) coordinate (a) node[black,left] {A}
    -- (2,4) coordinate (b) node[black,above] {B}
    -- (7,0) coordinate (c) node[black,right] {C}
    pic["$\alpha$", draw=orange, -, angle eccentricity=1.2, angle radius=1cm]
    {angle=a--b--c}
        pic["$\beta$", draw=orange, -, angle eccentricity=1.2, angle radius=1cm]
    {angle=c--a--b}
        pic["$\gamma$", draw=orange, -, angle eccentricity=1.2, angle radius=1cm]
    {angle=b--c--a}-- cycle;
    \tkzInCenter(a,b,c)
    \tkzGetPoint{d}
    \tkzDrawPoint(d)
    \draw[red] (a) -- (d)--(intersection of  a--d and b--c);
    \draw[red] (b) -- (d)--(intersection of  b--d and a--c);
    \draw[red] (c) -- (d)--(intersection of  c--d and b--a);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

And here is a version with a macro and all the not immediately necessary stuff removed.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,angles}

\newcommand{\DrawBisector}[4][red]{
\tkzFindSlopeAngle(#3,#2)
\let\tmpAngle=\tkzAngleResult
\tkzFindAngle(#2,#3,#4)
\draw[red] (#3) + (\tmpAngle+\tkzAngleResult/2:1) --(#3);
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[blue, very thick]
    (0,0) coordinate (a) node[black,left] {A}
    -- (2,4) coordinate (b) node[black,above] {B}
    -- (7,0) coordinate (c) node[black,right] {C}
    pic["$\alpha$", draw=orange, -, angle eccentricity=1.2, angle radius=1cm]
    {angle=a--b--c}
        pic["$\beta$", draw=orange, -, angle eccentricity=1.2, angle radius=1cm]
    {angle=c--a--b}
        pic["$\gamma$", draw=orange, -, angle eccentricity=1.2, angle radius=1cm]
    {angle=b--c--a}-- cycle;
    \DrawBisector{a}{b}{c}
    \DrawBisector{b}{c}{a}
    \DrawBisector{c}{a}{b}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And for those who neither speak French nor feel easy about looking up the definitions of the macros in the source code of tkz-euclide, here is a Ti*k*Z "only" solution that computes the incenter and then draws the bisectors. (The determination of the incenter has already been accomplished by Mark Wibrow in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/294444/121799). All I did was to, more or less, to translate his tikzmath code to a code using the calc library since this is arguably easier to use.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,angles,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[blue, very thick]
    (0,0) coordinate (a) node[black,left] {A} 
    -- (2,4) coordinate (b) node[black,above] {B}
    -- (7,0) coordinate (c) node[black,right] {C}
    pic["$\alpha$", draw=orange, -, angle eccentricity=1.2, angle radius=1cm]
    {angle=a--b--c}
        pic["$\beta$", draw=orange, -, angle eccentricity=1.2, angle radius=1cm]
    {angle=c--a--b}
        pic["$\gamma$", draw=orange, -, angle eccentricity=1.2, angle radius=1cm]
    {angle=b--c--a}-- cycle;
    \path let \p1=(a),\p2=(b),\p3=(c),\n1={veclen(\x2-\x3,\y2-\y3)+veclen(\x1-\x3,\y1-\y3)
    +veclen(\x2-\x1,\y2-\y1)},
    \n2={veclen(\x2-\x3,\y2-\y3)/\n1},
    \n3={veclen(\x1-\x3,\y1-\y3)/\n1},\n4={veclen(\x2-\x1,\y2-\y1)/\n1}
     in coordinate (incenter) at (barycentric cs:a=\n2,b=\n3,c=\n4);
   \fill[red] (incenter) circle (1pt);
   \foreach \X in {a,b,c}
   {\draw[red] (\X) -- ($(\X)!1cm!(incenter)$);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**UPDATE**: Lines extend to the opposite edges.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,angles,calc,intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[blue, very thick]
    (0,0) coordinate (a) node[black,left] {A} 
    -- (2,4) coordinate (b) node[black,above] {B}
    -- (7,0) coordinate (c) node[black,right] {C}
    pic["$\alpha$", draw=orange, -, angle eccentricity=1.2, angle radius=1cm]
    {angle=a--b--c}
        pic["$\beta$", draw=orange, -, angle eccentricity=1.2, angle radius=1cm]
    {angle=c--a--b}
        pic["$\gamma$", draw=orange, -, angle eccentricity=1.2, angle radius=1cm]
    {angle=b--c--a} -- cycle;
    \path let \p1=(a),\p2=(b),\p3=(c),\n1={veclen(\x2-\x3,\y2-\y3)+veclen(\x1-\x3,\y1-\y3)
    +veclen(\x2-\x1,\y2-\y1)},
    \n2={veclen(\x2-\x3,\y2-\y3)/\n1},
    \n3={veclen(\x1-\x3,\y1-\y3)/\n1},\n4={veclen(\x2-\x1,\y2-\y1)/\n1}
     in coordinate (incenter) at (barycentric cs:a=\n2,b=\n3,c=\n4);
   \fill[red] (incenter) circle (1pt);
   \path[name path=c] (a) -- (b);
   \path[name path=b] (a) -- (c);
   \path[name path=a] (c) -- (b);
   \foreach \X in {a,b,c}
   {\path[overlay,name path=aux] (\X) -- ($(\X)!12cm!(incenter)$);
   \draw[red,name intersections={of=aux and \X,by=i-\X}] (\X) -- (i-\X); 
   }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much MARMOT BUT I want the lines from a corner to a edge

Comment: @ihsan I see. Made an update.

Answer (score 2):

The midpoint of a line segment BC is easily computed with the calc library. The line joining a vertex A to the midpoint of BC is the angle bisector only if the triangle ABC is isosceles. But we can make an isosceles triangle APQ by intersecting ABC with the unit circle at A. If M is the midpoint of PQ, then the intersection X of AM and BC yields the angle bisector AX.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (B) at (0,0);
\coordinate (C) at (7,0);
\coordinate (A) at (1,3);

\draw[name path=triangle]  (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;
\path[name path=circle] (A)  circle [radius=1pt];
\path [name intersections={of=triangle and circle}];

\coordinate (P) at (intersection-1);
\coordinate (Q) at (intersection-2);
\coordinate (M) at ($.5*(P)+.5*(Q)$);
\coordinate (X) at (intersection of {B--C} and {A--M});

\draw (A) -- (X);

\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

[image: bisector]

Answer (score 1):

Using `origin` instead of `\rput` to displace the last 3 lines in [Herbert's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/442713/12187).

```
\documentclass[pstricks,margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(7.5,5)
\pstGeonode[PointSymbol=none,PosAngle={180,90,0}](0,0){A}(2,4){B}(7,0){C}
\pspolygon[linecolor=blue,linewidth=1pt](A)(B)(C)
\psset{MarkAngleRadius=0.8,linecolor=red}
\pstMarkAngle{C}{A}{B}{$\alpha$}
\pstMarkAngle{A}{B}{C}{$\beta$}
\pstMarkAngle{B}{C}{A}{$\gamma$}
\bgroup
    \psset{linestyle=none,PointSymbol=none,PointName=none}
    \pstBissectBAC{C}{A}{B}{A'}
    \pstBissectBAC{A}{B}{C}{B'}
    \pstBissectBAC{B}{C}{A}{C'}
\egroup
\bgroup
    \psset{PointName=none,linestyle=dashed,linecolor=black}
    \pstInterLL{A}{B}{C}{C'}{AB}\psline(C)(AB)
    \pstInterLL{B}{C}{A}{A'}{BC}\psline(A)(BC)
    \pstInterLL{C}{A}{B}{B'}{CA}\psline(B)(CA)
\egroup
\psline[origin=A](0.8;{(A')})
\psline[origin=B](0.8;{(B')})
\psline[origin=C](0.8;{(C')})
\end{pspicture}    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`tzplot`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tzplot):

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone} 

\usepackage{tzplot}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\scriptsize]
\tzcoors(0,0)(a){A}[l](2,4)(b){B}(7,0)(c){C}[r];
\tzpolygon[blue,very thick](a)(b)(c);
\tzanglemark(b)(a)(c){$\alpha$}
\tzcoor*[red](tzAAmid)(am)(1.5pt)
\tzanglemark(a)(b)(c){$\beta$}
\tzcoor*[red](tzAAmid)(bm)(1.5pt)
\tzanglemark(a)(c)(b){$\gamma$}
\tzcoor*[red](tzAAmid)(cm)(1.5pt)
\tzline[red]"aa"(a)(intersection of a--am and b--c)
\tzline[red]"bb"(b)(intersection of b--bm and a--c)
\tzline[red]"cc"(c)(intersection of c--cm and a--b)
\tzXpoint*{aa}{bb}(X)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```